# Altering numbers/date and adding + one week. Not with date() - in PHP

Tags: php, database, date, time

I have:

PHP code: `$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");` and send this to my datebase

I use

```
$date = $gg['date'];
```

to get the date from my datebase
When I `echo $date` -> `June 30, 2012, 3:45 pm`

The time is already set in the database with mail.php, and in ordertracking.php I'm getting that time and want to add one week to it.

So I want to add one week to: `$date = $gg['date'];`

```
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Can't connect");
mysql_select_db("shoppingcart", $connection) or die ("Can't connect");

$ordertracking = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ordertracking` WHERE orderid='$orderid'");
while($gg=mysql_fetch_array($ordertracking))
{
    $progress = $gg['progress'];
    $date = $gg['date'];
}

mysql_close($connection)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047375/php-date-manipulation

Comment: I have tried this `$d = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
$end_date = date(“Y m d”,strtotime(“+2 days”,$d));` but it did not work. Also tried `$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");` did not work. I did change the variables of course

Comment: @robert no it's not a dubplicate, my problem is way different than what you have posted.

Comment: Please edit the question. Also note roberts comment and take a look at the php DateTime Class: http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` `modify()` method

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("F j, Y, g:i a", $date);
$dt->modify('+1 week');
echo $dt->format("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here some simple solution)

```
$date = date( 'F j, Y, g:i a' );
echo date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime( $date ) + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 );
```

Comment: This gives me `January 8, 1970, 1:00 am` But Ziumin gave me the good code. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat to use the strtotime method you would do

```
$date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime('2012-06-30 3:45 pm +1 week'));
```

Comment: This gives me `2012-03-11`, does not fix my problem

Comment: I updated my code to show you exact time you were using.. How does this not fix your problem? It adds exactly one week like you requested

Comment: No this will do the same, I do not want to enter the date manually. It is set in the database. I've changed my question, but the problem is fixed with Ziumin's solution. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$date = 'June 30, 2012, 3:45 pm';

$new_date = date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime(date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ziumin's solution fixed my problem. Thank you anyways

Comment: @F4LLCON It's OK. Any way i reccoomend you to use the method that I have specified which is much faster than Ziumin's method.. :)