# Changing date format in mysql_fetch returned array

Tags: php

I have a query like this

```
select fname,joined_date from employees where id=1
```

currently the date format I'm using to display this returned employee details is Y-m-d.
But now I need to convert the default mysql format Y-m-d to d/m/Y(in all date information display fields).

For me it's **very very difficult** to go through all the files to do the date format conversion.

So I thought of doing some thing like this in my database class.I have a function like this in my database class

```
function fetch($res){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   foreach($row as $key=>$value){
   if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/',$value))
      $row[$key] = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($value));
   }
   return $row;
}//end function
```

and i'm using this function like this

```
$row = $db->fetch($res);
```

or

```
while($row = $db->fetch($res)){...}
```

I'm getting the expected output,but with an error message

> invalid argument for foreach

it looks like the fetch function code executed (total_num_rows + 1) times

If I use for loop instead of foreach, getting undefined offset error

currently I'm using some thing like this to escape

```
if(is_array($row)){...}
```

when i look for the type $res,
it showed 
resource(1st iteration),resource(2nd)

for $row array

array(1st iteration),boolean(2nd)

Can anybody tell me why it's happening?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php, date manipulation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047375/php-date-manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

When you reach the end of the results, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns `false`. You need to check for that case:

```
function fetch($res){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   if ($row) {
     foreach($row as $key=>$value){
       if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/',$value)){
          $row[$key] = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($value));
       }
     }
   }
   return $row;
}
```

Comment: yes I'm checking is_array($row)..and no error comes.But i just want to know why it's looping again?

Comment: When you do `while ($row = $db->fetch())` it has to call fetch an extra time to detect that it has reached the end.

Comment: but just $db->fetch() (without while) also returns the same error for me

Comment: if I use just $db->fetch(), it's executing two times and second iteration comes with an error

Comment: I can't explain that.

Comment: I know I'm missing something,but couldn't find where to correct my code.

Comment: It must be because of some other part of your code, because there's nothing wrong with the `fetch` function that would make it fetch twice.

Answer (score 0):

if you want this format for ex: June 19, 2015
use this: 
date("F d, Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
where $myrow['date'] is what you are fetching from mysql row wise
check this link for further assistance: http://erikastokes.com/mysql-help/display-mysql-dates-in-other-formats.php

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score -1):

It is easier to have you convert the date to the desired format already in the MySQL command.
example:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%d-%y") AS date FROM my_table;
```